# SQLite Delete Query Error: no such column: ID (code 1)

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to delete a row in my SQLite db in my app. It keeps on crashing with

no such column: ID (code 1)

I've tried

db.delete(TABLE_NAME, "ID=?", new String[]{Integer.toString(numID)});

but I still end up with the same

DB Structure:

```
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME +
            " (ITEM_ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
            "NAME TEXT, " +
            "PRICE INTEGER, " +
            "DATE TEXT);");
    }
```

Deletion query:

```
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        String query = "DELETE FROM " + TABLE_NAME + " WHERE " + ITEM_ID + " = '" + Integer.toString(numID ) + "'";
        db.execSQL(query);
```

My other select queries work perfectly fine so any help would be appreciated

Comment: The column is apparently named `ITEM_ID`, not `ID`.

Comment: You've named the column ITEM_ID, so change your `delete` to refer to that.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to delete by `ID`, but your table uses `ITEM_ID`

change

```
 db.delete(TABLE_NAME, "ID=?", new String[]{Integer.toString(numID)});
```

to

```
 db.delete(TABLE_NAME, "ITEM_ID=?", new String[]{Integer.toString(numID)});
```

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't ITEM_ID need to be within the "", rather than a variable??

```
String query = "DELETE FROM " + TABLE_NAME + " WHERE ITEM_ID='" + Integer.toString(numID) + "'";
```